# Where should custom Wcf service for SharePoint 2010 resides?

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-object-model

I want to create Wcf service for SharePoint 2010. I strictly want to use server object model. I have gone through two articles http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=760

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/step-by-step-building-custom-wcf-services-hosted-in-sharepoint-part-i/

I want to know if we are using sharepoint 2010 server object model then is it mandatory that custom wcf must reside on the same machine on which sharepoint is installed (as decribed in second link) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the server object model you have to host your WCF service on the same server as your SharePoint is installed on.

If the WCF service has to be on a different server you can use the client object model or the SharePoint webservices to communicate to SharePoint.

[(link to a question about using server object model on different server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42615/can-you-call-spsite-on-a-different-machine-to-sharepoint-setup)

Answer (score 0):

I think, thows articles sre different.

Second one described how to host your wcf service "inside" share point env., when the first one describe communication between them.

For first model - it is nothing more then some wcf service, calling some SharePoint api (server model?).
Inthis case - they can be hosted in different machines as well.

Comment: means if I want to use server object model then I must host my wcf service inside sharepoint environment?

Comment: http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/deploying-custom-wcf-service-to-iis-vs-sharepoint/. This article decribes we need to host wcf services in sharepoint environment if we want to use server object model

Comment: My fault - u'd use Client Object model, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535231(v=office.14).aspx